# Magento: Export customers from version 1.5 and import them in Version 1.8.1

Tags: magento-1.8, customer, import

Hi I have developed a new shop in magento version 1.8.1 and my previous shop was in version 1.5.1. Now I want to import the customers from the old shop into the new shop. I have used "**Data Flow Profiles**" for this but it is not importing it to the new system. It is giving me the error of "**Website not defined**". I have tried different things in the csv but nothing worked for me. Is this the version problem with both the system.

So how can i do that. Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

For importing customer, there is a field called _website in the csv, check if that field is present in the csv you are trying to import.

For simplicity, create a new customer in the new store and export it, then you can see what extra fields you require in your csv to import it to the store

Comment: "Simplicity", Solution is the best one.. +1 for u..